# Is it a bad idea to add lots of machines as submit hosts in an SGE environment?

Tags: gridengine

We're replacing a home-grown queueing system with SGE/OGE.  The current work environment has engineers using their own local Linux workstation to submit jobs.  So I'm wondering about adding many machines as submit hosts to an SGE/OGE cluster.  In our case, there would probably be on the order of 100-200 submit hosts submitting jobs to a cluster that has approximately 30-50 execution nodes.

I think that's backward from what is "normal" where there is a single submit host (or maybe just a couple) which serves as the front-end to the cluster.  Are there any down-sides to having lots of submit hosts (other than having to add them via qconf)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are any downsides other than keeping track of which hosts are submit hosts, I haven't seen them. To the best of my knowledge, GridEngine only ever checks the list at submission time and never initiates any connections from the server to the submit hosts.

In our environment all our workstations, exec hosts, and a number of other machines are set up as submit hosts and thus far I have not seen any detrimental effects as a result. The total count is around 120.

We allow job submission from user workstations as well as having a gateway machine that can be accessed via SSH for VPN users.

Comment: Thanks - nice tip about the gateway machine for remote users.